# Can't reseed tiles on mapproxy from geoserver wms

Tags: tiles, mapproxy

I am confused on how to initiate reseeding in mapproxy. I used the file mapproxy.yaml and seed.yaml for the first seeding. Its source has been significantly updated. So I want to cache everything anew. This `mapproxy-seed -f mapproxy.yaml -s seed.yaml` doesn't work (tiles weren't created like  with the dry run setting). I failed with this too:

```
--reseed-interval 90d --reseed-file reseed.time \
--continue --progress-file .mapproxy_seed_progress
```

How can I reseed tiles?
This my yaml file:

```
# ---------------------------------------
# MapProxy example seeding configuration.
# ---------------------------------------
#
# This is a minimal MapProxy seeding configuration.
# See full_seed_example.yaml and the documentation for more options.
#

seeds:
  myseed1:
    caches: [osm_cache]
    # grids: []
    # coverages: []
    levels:
      to: 12
   # refresh_before:
    #  time: 2013-10-10T12:35:00

#cleanups:
 # myclean1:
  #  caches: [osm_cache]
   # remove_before:
    #  days: 14
    #levels:
     #   from: 11

#coverages:
```

```
# -------------------------------
# MapProxy example configuration.
# -------------------------------
#
# This is a minimal MapProxy configuration.
# See full_example.yaml and the documentation for more options.
#

# Starts the following services:
# Demo:
#     http://localhost:8080/demo
# WMS:
#     capabilities: http://localhost:8080/service?REQUEST=GetCapabilities
# WMTS:
#     capabilities: http://localhost:8080/wmts/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml
#     first tile: http://localhost:8080/wmts/osm/webmercator/0/0/0.png
# Tile service (compatible with OSM/etc.)
#     first tile: http://localhost:8080/tiles/osm/webmercator/0/0/0.png
# TMS:
#     note: TMS is not compatible with OSM/Google Maps/etc.
#     fist tile: http://localhost:8080/tms/1.0.0/osm/webmercator/0/0/0.png
# KML:
#     initial doc: http://localhost:8080/kml/osm/webmercator
services:
  demo:
  tms:
    use_grid_names: true
    # origin for /tiles service
    origin: 'nw'
  kml:
      use_grid_names: true
  wmts:
    # use restful access to WMTS
    restful: true
    # this is the default template for MapProxy
    restful_template: '/{Layer}/{TileMatrixSet}/{TileMatrix}/{TileCol}/{TileRow}.{Format}'
    # and also allow KVP requests
    kvp: true
  wms:
    md:
      title: MapProxy WMS Proxy
      abstract: This is a minimal MapProxy example.

layers:
  - name: osm_background
    title: osm_background
    sources: [osm_cache]

caches:
  #geoserver cache:
  gasps_osm_cache:
    # cache the results in two grids/projections
    grids: [osm_grid]
    sources: [osm_source]

sources:
  gasps_osm_source:
    type: wms
    req:
      url: 'http:/xxx.local:xxxx/geoserver/wspace/wms'
      layers: wspace:layer
grids:
    osm_grid:
        base: GLOBAL_MERCATOR
        srs: 'EPSG:3857'
        origin: nw

globals:
```

Comment: you say you failed, what went wrong?

Comment: I solved it by adding refresh_before setting. Failed cause seeding looks like run with -n key (dry run). 0 tiles were creted.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set `refresh_before` or `cleanups : remove_before:` setting in your seed.yaml. Without them new tiles will not be created.